# how to get datetime list using stream in Elixir

Tags: elixir

how I can get a list of DateTime between 2 datetimes using stream with a specific interval.

I did this

```
stream = Stream.iterate(starting, &(Calendar.DateTime.add!(&1, 1200)))
```

1200 is the interval which I want to add to the date each time.

It works fine when I do this.

```
iex(16)> {:ok, after_seconds, 0, :after} = Calendar.DateTime.diff(ending, starting)
{:ok, 691200, 0, :after}
iex(17)> chunk = after_seconds / 1200 |> trunc
576
```

576 is the chunk values I need from start datetime till the end datetime

on doing

```
Enum.take(stream, chunk)
```

Assuming this is the starting and ending datetime

```
iex(14)> starting = Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!({{2020, 1, 25},{0, 29, 10}}, "Etc/UTC", {123456, 6}) |> Calendar.DateTime.shift_zone!("Europe/Dublin")
#DateTime<2020-01-25 00:29:10.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>
iex(15)> ending = Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!({{2020, 2, 2},{0, 29, 10}}, "Etc/UTC", {123456, 6}) |> Calendar.DateTime.shift_zone!("Europe/Dublin")   
#DateTime<2020-02-02 00:29:10.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>
```

but is very slow. how I can make it faster? what could be the better solution than this?

out of this should be like this

```
[#DateTime<2020-01-25 00:00:00.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>,
 #DateTime<2020-01-25 00:20:00.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>,
 #DateTime<2020-01-25 00:40:00.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>,
 #DateTime<2020-01-25 01:00:00.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>,
 ....
 #DateTime<2020-01-25 23:40:00.123456+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>
 ]
```

Comment: What's the exact expected output for the two values?

Comment: a list of dates. starting from the starting date and ending at the ending date..

and between starting and ending there should be dates as last date + interval.

Comment: Taking 576 values from `Stream.iterate` takes about 35-40ms for me. Do you want it to be faster than that?

Comment: yes can it be?  I am just wondering some one pointed me on slack that this will be slow and there are other methods to do that, But I am not aware of

Comment: You could use Elixir's builtin `NaiveDateTime` which ignores timezone and do the conversion if/when needed. It's about 10 times faster to add NaiveDateTime for me. Let's see if someone has a better idea.

Comment: But i dont want to ignore the timezone that the issue here.

Comment: but if you can propose NativeDateTime solution then I can do timezone conversion later.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need a `DateTime`? Or would a `Date` work just fine? Based on the way that you've phrased your question, I would try starting with a `Date`, iterating the `Stream` by using [`Date.add`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#add/2), and then take however many you need.